# Python 3.6 how to check to see if a list contains a string with letters and also contains an integer?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I check to see if a list contains a string that itself does not contain any digits? The list in question will have a string with letters or digits and an integer.

Comment: Which part are you struggling with?  Use `isinstance` to only deal with strings, and something like `not any(map(str.isidigit, s))` to check if any of the characters are digits

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of a list comprehension to iterate over the `input_list`, `any()` to return `True` the second you encounter the first string with an `int()` (early exits are always a good idea), and a regex to see if a digit or letter is in the string (`[0-9]` matches any single digit and `[a-zA-Z]` any letter in a string; `re.search()` will evaluate `True` if either of thesestrings match).

Based on the question, you want to check if any string inside the list contains at least one letter and at least one number, but if it has only numbers or letters it is fine. I'm not exactly sure which condition you wish to check for ; If my interpretation is off, I am happy to edit the code below to match your intent.

```
import re
input_list = [11, "11", "somestring", "someotherstring", "mixedstring1"]
any([x for x in input_list if re.search("[0-9]", str(x)) and re.search("[a-zA-Z]", str(x))])
```

`True`

Answer (score 0):

Your Q is unclear, but I think that for this list:

```
l = ['bob', 'fish', 'abc123']
```

you want to `False` as the list *does* contain a string with digits.

And for the following:

```
l = ['bob', 'fish', 'abc']
```

you want `True` as there are no strings with digits.

To achieve both of these results, you can use:

```
not any(any(c.isdigit() for c  in s) for s in l)
```